# Referencing BibTeX file on network drive (UNC)

Tags: bibtex, filesystem-access

Hello fellow typesetters.

I've messed with bibliographies before, creating a bibliography file for every folder where there were .tex files that needed them. Recently though, I ventured to create a central bibliography that would be easier to manage. Since I work on the move, I'd like to put this in my cloud. For my desktop computer though, this cloud is best accessed using the local network, since it doesn't require sending the file over and back via FTP.

My question is for a Windows computer: How can I reference my .bib file on a network drive? Normally, the file would be called:

```
\\MEROVINGIAN\Public\LaTeX\bibliography.bib
```

This should reference the file through the local network. However, backslashes don't work with BibTeX, so I tried using this command in TeXstudio for BibTeX:

```
bibtex.exe % --include-directory="//MEROVINGIAN/Public/LaTeX"
```

and then referencing the bibliography with the following command in my document:

```
\bibliography{bibliography}
```

However, it doesn't seem to work. None of the references to the bibliography could be found. When I load up NetDrive and map the cloud to a drive letter it does work:

```
bibtex.exe % --include-directory="M:/LaTeX"
```

However, this then goes through NetDrive and subsequently through FTP. My question is as follows: How would I configure BibTeX to find this bibliography file without having to go through NetDrive? Is there a format that needs to be used to access these folders, or is it simply impossible?

Edit: I believe these are called UNC paths.

Comment: Is there a specific reason that simply mapping the drive is undesirable? Does it work using the standard Windows drive map utility?

Comment: On UNIX systems you can use the `BIBTEX` environment variable to tell BibTeX where to look. Presumably there is a windows equivalent?

Comment: I just tried mapping "//MEROVINGIAN/Public" to a drive letter in Windows, and using bibtex.exe % --include-directory="K:/LaTeX", but it still didn't find it. Then I tried using M:/LaTeX again, but it couldn't find that either (though I tried that yesterday with succes!) I must be doing something wrong. I have no `BIBTEX` environment variable (or anything similar) set for this machine, it finds BibTeX via the %PATH% environment variable.